# Call shell script for each image ffmpeg processes (timelapse)

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg

I'd like `ffmpeg` to call a shell script each time it processes a new image, and to send that filename to the script and ideally also send the filename of the next image it'll process (if any).

This is my `ffmpeg` command so far (for a jpg -> mov timelapse).

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i "/images/*.jpg" -c copy "lapse.mov"
```

I've had a look through some of the `ffmpeg` documentation, but nothing shows up on my keyword searches, but there is a lot of documentation, so maybe I'm missing something?

My ultimate goal with this is so I can put the next filename into a text file for ffmpeg's `drawtext textfile` to read, and thus render onto the next frame. I realise this can be done in a split step process, but I'm seeing how far I can push a single ffmpeg command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can do it the way that you're asking for, but the updating of `drawtext` can be achieved with `sendcmd` by generating a command file with the time intervals and the filenames hard-coded in it.

That said, given the frame rate and the glob (expanding to the image files) you can generate the corresponding command file programmatically:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

framerate=25
imglob='images/*.jpg'

awk -v framerate="$framerate" '
    BEGIN {
        OFS = "\t"
        time = 0
        step = 1 / framerate
        for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) {
            n = split(ARGV[i],path,"/")
            filename = path[n]
            print time, "[enter]", "drawtext", "reinit", "text="filename";"
            time += step
        }
        exit
      }
' $imglob > cmd.txt

ffmpeg -framerate "$framerate" \
       -pattern_type glob -i "$imglob" \
       -vf "sendcmd=f=cmd.txt" \
       -c copy "lapse.mov"
```

**Note:** bash doesn't have any floating point capabilities, that's why I *hijacked* `awk` here.

---

If your filenames contain characters that can break the command file format then you'll have to store each filename in a different text file and use `textfile=textfile_with_the_filename.txt` instead of `text=literal_filename` in the command file.